# calculate the length of line using toString

Tags: java, object, tostring

I need to Implement the classes Point and Line
The toString method of Point Should print a point in the form (x,y) 
The toString method of Line Should print a point in the form  (x1,y1)->(x2,y2)

Then I need to create a Class called LineApp
in the main do the following:
Create a Line with the points (0,0) and (4,3)
Then calculate and display the length of the line.

I have been looking at this and have no clue what to do

Comment: Start by implementing the classes Point and Line. The toString method of Point should print a point in the form (x,y). The toString method of Line Should print a point in the form (x1,y1)->(x2,y2)...

Comment: How can you not possibly have a clue of what to do.  If you're really as clueless as you say, then the very first thing you must do is spend some quality time with the Java Tutorial.

Comment: I took an introductory course at my community college then they merged majors and now I am in this new class with almost none of this looking familiar

Comment: I'd recommend - Go speak to your lecturer as soon as possible and explain the problem to him/her and ask if (s)he can recommend a good tutorial or book to catch up with. Having this information out there helps (in most cases) - it can allow you to ask elementary questions without being judged too harshly, and you may even be given extra time to complete assignments. Then go in search of a good tutorial or book, who knows the quality of what (s)he'd recommend. And no, you shouldn't ask for a recommendation as a [so] question, this classifies as 'not constructive' and will be closed.

Comment: [so] is not the appropriate place to learn a language. Maybe to learn something here and there, but not from scratch.

Comment: its not that this is all new for me the class started to cover things, but the jump to this course was staggering... I was under the impression this was an open forum for asking questions??? After seeing the post below I was actually not that far off maybe because i feel so far behind im making it out to be worse than it actually is... thank you for your suggestions and help!

Comment: Yes, [so] is an open forum for asking questions, but asking for a recommendation for a tutorial or book is classifies as ['not constructive'](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) because, for one thing, there is no real 'right' answer.

Comment: oh ok thank you for clarifying that I will take the advice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `toString()` method of the `Point` class should look like:

```
public String toString() {
   return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
}
```

The `toString()` method of the `Line` class should look like (supposing you have two members of type `Point` in the class `Line`):

```
public String toString() {
   return "(" + point_A.getX() + "," + point_A.getY() + ")->" +
          "(" + point_B.getX() + "," + point_B.getY() + ");
}
```

Mathematically, if you have two points: A(x1, y1) and B(x2, y2), the length of the line AB will be calculated with this formula:

```
AB * AB = (x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1)
```

Thus, you can do the following thin in your code:

```
Double length = Math.sqrt((x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1));
System.out.println(length);
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, the toString() method for the Line class would look something like:

```
public String toString() {
    return "(" + x1 + "," + y1 + ")->(" + x2 + "," + y2 + ")";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first  `@override` the object class before you customize your own `toString()` method.